# which one is proper method of writing this gl code

Tags: c++, opengl, frame-rate

i have been doing some experiments with opengl and handling textures.
in my experiment i have a 2d array of (int) which are randomly generated

```
 int mapskeleton[300][300];
```

then  after that i have my own obj file loader for loading obj with textures

```
m2d wall,floor;//i initialize and load those files at start
```

for recording statistics of render times i used

```
bool Once = 1; 
int secs = 0;
```

now to the render code here i did my experiment

```
    //  Code A: Benchmarked on radeon 8670D   
    //  Takes 232(average) millisecs for drawing 300*300 tiles

if(Once)
secs = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);

for(int i=0;i<mapHeight;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<mapWidth;j++){
        if(mapskeleton[j][i] == skel_Wall){
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,wall.texture);
            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(j*10,i*10,0);      
            wall.Draw();//Draws 10 textured triangles
            glPopMatrix();
        }
        if(mapskeleton[j][i] == skel_floor){
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,floor.texture);
            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(j*10,i*10,0);      
            floor.Draw();//Draws 2 textured triangles
            glPopMatrix();
        }           

    }
}
if(Once){
secs = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)-secs;
printf("time taken for rendering %i msecs",secs)
Once = 0;
}
```

and  other code is

```
    //  Code B:    Benchmarked on radeon 8670D   
    //  Takes 206(average) millisecs for drawing 300*300 tiles


if(Once)
secs = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);  

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,floor.texture);

for(int i=0;i<mapHeight;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<mapWidth;j++){
        if(mapskeleton[j][i] == skel_floor){
            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(j*10,i*10,0);      
            floor.Draw();
            glPopMatrix();
        }
    }
}
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,wall.texture);

for(int i=0;i<mapHeight;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<mapWidth;j++){
        if(mapskeleton[j][i] == skel_Wall){
            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(j*10,i*10,0);      
            wall.Draw();
            glPopMatrix();
        }
    }
}   
if(Once){
secs = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)-secs;
printf("time taken for rendering %i msecs",secs)
Once = 0;
}
```

for me code A looks good with a point of a person(Beginner) viewing code. but benchmarks say different.
my gpu seems to like code B. I don't understand why does code B takes less time to render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes to OpenGL state can generally be expensive - the driver's and/or GPUs data structures and caches can become invalidated. In your case, the change in question is binding a different texture. In code B, you're doing it twice. In code A, you're easily doing it thousands of times.

When programming OpenGL rendering, you'll generally want to set up the pipeline for settings A, render everything which needs settings A, re-set the pipeline for settings B, render everything which needs settings B, and so on.

Comment: So binding texture every iteration is not a good thing. What about the translation , gltranslatef function does it also slow down the rendering process?

Comment: @Fennekin But that's something you can't avoid. You want to render each square in a different place, so you *have to* change its position. Not to mention the fact that `glTranslate()` is just a matrix multiplication, that should be very fast in and of itself.

Comment: Of course, this is really an example of 'which is the least horrible way of doing this?'  The proper way to do this would be to push all the wall and floor positions to the GPU in your setup and then draw the whole thing at once using instanced rendering and either one or two draw calls for the entire maze.

Answer (score 1):

@Angew covered why one options is more efficient than the other. But there is an important point that needs to be stated very clearly. Based on the text of your question, particularly here:

> for recording statistics of render times
>
> my gpu seems to like code B

you seem to attempt to measure rendering/GPU performance.

### You are NOT AT ALL measuring GPU performance!

You measure the time for setting up the state and making the draw calls. OpenGL lets the GPU operate asynchronously from the code executed on the CPU. The picture you should keep in mind when you make (most) OpenGL calls is that you're **submitting work** to the GPU for later execution. There's no telling when the GPU completes that work. It most definitely (except for very few calls that you want to avoid in speed critical code) does not happen by the time the call returns.

What you're measuring in your code is purely the **CPU overhead** for making these calls. This includes what's happening in your own code, and what happens in the driver code for handling the calls and preparing the work for later submission to the GPU.

I'm not saying that the measurement is not useful. Minimizing CPU overhead is very important. You just need to be very aware of what you are in fact measuring, and make sure that you draw the right conclusions.